# Return the highest count record

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group

The data I am working on looks like below-

```
A_ID          B_ID           count
123           abcd          1000
123           aaaa          2000
123           aaaa          3000
456           null          50
456           bbbb          6000
456           cccc          450
```

I want to be able to extract the B_id that has the highest count for a given A_id

The result should look like-

```
A_ID          B_ID        count
123           aaaa        3000
456           bbbb        6000
```

How to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to filter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.count = (select max(t1.count) from mytable t1 where t1.a_id = t.a_id)
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.* except(rn)
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by a_id order by count desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation in BigQuery:

```
select array_agg(t order by count desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from t
group by a_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY a_id
```

if to apply to sample data from  your question - the output is

```
Row a_id    b_id    count    
1   123     aaaa    3000     
2   456     bbbb    6000
```