# Return the highest count record based on a condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For the question in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62460163/11035754), I have one more column called **date** which has the data type **timestamp**. I want to check 2 conditions-

1. only consider B_ID's which have count >= 2000 in a month
2. then return the B_ID with the highest count in the group

How to achieve this result?

Comment: . . You should provide sample data and desired results in this question.  This is especially true because the data in the question you point to is irrelevant to this question (it has no date for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your condition in where clause

```
select t.* except(rn)
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by a_id order by count desc) rn
    from mytable t where count>=2000
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery you can do this without a subquery, by using aggregation:

```
select (array_agg(t order by count desc limit 1))[ordinal(1)].*
from t
where count >= 2000
group by timestamp_trunc(timestamp, month);
```

If you want to use window functions, then an alternative is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by timestamp_trunc(timestamp, month) order by count desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where count >= 2000
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```